# Unable to free a struct inside an array

Tags: arrays, c, struct, memory-leaks

I am working on a project where I'm trying to manipulate a struct (WorkTree) containing an array of structs (WorkFiles). What I am trying to do is :

1. allocating the memory for the WorkTree,
2. allocating the memory for two WorkFiles,
3. fill the WorkTree array with the WorkFiles,
4. free everything.

From what I understand, the array contains the struct itself and not a pointer towards it, which seems to create problems in the free() functions. I'm not sure why, I've tried changing the parameters of the free() function without any success. The structure itself is imposed on me and therefore can not be changed. Here's the code and the valgrind message.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated !

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    char* hash;
    int mode;
} WorkFile;

typedef struct {
    WorkFile* tab;
    int size;
    int n;
} WorkTree;

type WorkFile* createWorkFile(char* name)
{
    WorkFile* wf = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile));
    wf->name = strdup(name);
    wf->mode = 0;
    
    return wf;
}

int inWorkTree(WorkTree* wt, char* name)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < wt->n)
    {
        if(strcmp(wt->tab[i].name, name) == 0) 
    {
        return i;
    }
    i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

int appendWorkTree(WorkTree* wt, char* name, char* hash, int mode)
{ 
    int res = inWorkTree(wt, name);
    
    if(res == -1)
    {
        WorkFile* new = createWorkFile(name);
    new->hash = strdup(hash);
    new->mode = mode;
    wt->tab[wt->n] = *new;
    wt->n = (wt->n) + 1;
    return 1;
    }
    
    return -1;
}

WorkTree* createWorkTree(int size)
{
    WorkTree* wt = (WorkTree*)malloc(sizeof(WorkTree));
    wt->tab = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile)*size);

    wt->n = 0;
    wt->size = size;
    
    return wt;
}

void freeWorkTree(WorkTree* wt)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    while(i < wt->n)
    {       
        free((&(wt->tab[i]))->name);
    free((&(wt->tab[i]))->hash);
    free(&(wt->tab[i]));
    i++;
    }

    free(wt->tab);
    free(wt);
}
```

Here is my main function :

```
int main()
{
    WorkTree* wt = createWorkTree(2);

    appendWorkTree(wt, "test", "blablabla", 12);
    appendWorkTree(wt, "test1", "bloublou", 10);

    freeWorkTree(wt);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the valgrind message :

[valgrind_memory_check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A9ye.png)

Comment: What is type in this declaration type WorkFile* createWorkFile(char* name)?

Comment: You need to decide if you want to allocate an array of WorkFiles or each WorkFile individually. Now it seems you are doing both.

Comment: The memory for `wt->tab` was allocated by `wt->tab = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile)*size);` and is freed by `free(wt->tab);`. Remove `free(&(wt->tab[i]));` because it is trying to free something in the middle of the allocated memory.

Comment: There is a memory leak in `appendWorkTree`. The memory pointed to by `new` (from `WorkFile* new = createWorkFile(name);`) is never freed.

Comment: You could consider declaring the `WorkTree` `tab` member as `WorkFile** tab` and use it like an array of pointers to `WorkFile`. Then you would need to change `wt->tab = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile)*size);` to `wt->tab = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile*)*size);` (or much preferably, `wt->tab = malloc(sizeof(*wt->tab)*size);`), change `wt->tab[i].` to `wt->tab[i]->`, change `wt->tab[wt->n] = *new;` to `wt->tab[wt->n] = new;`, change `&(wt->tab[i])` to `wt->tab[i]`, and keep the `free(wt->tab[i]);` (was `free(&(wt->tab[i]));`) call in the `while` loop as it points to allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The array that you allocate here:

```
    wt->tab = (WorkFile*)malloc(sizeof(WorkFile)*size);
```

In C that is one single chunk of memory, and has to be freed as one chunk. The contents are up to you to manage, though the compiler will tell you the size of the elements so you can index with `[]`. If you want to delete one in the middle, you need code to shift the remaining elements to fill the hole, or have some way to mark that memory as "unused".

C has a function `realloc()` which will take a pointer from `malloc()` and a new size, and return a pointer to new memory with the contents copied over. It's useful if you need to add elements to the end, or if you want to truncate by removing elements from the end, but of course it's doing a copy operation so has that overhead. You could take the last element, copy it over the element you want to delete, then `realloc()` memory that's smaller by 1 element (`sizeof(WorkFile)*size-1)`). That changes the order, so if it's sorted then that won't work.